# PowerShell based programs

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

Does anyone know how the consoles of programs like Lync, Exchange or SCVM was written?

They execute PowerShell scripts. Is there any SDK?

Answer (score 3):

You can embed a powershell space execution in a .NET program. You can find details on how to do that in [Writing a Windows PowerShell Host Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563%28v=vs.85%29) from Microsoft [Windows PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835506%28v=vs.85%29) site. It exists also non Microsoft sites like [How to run PowerShell scripts from C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C) or [How to Embed PowerShell Within a C# Application](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2010/04/08/how-to-embed-powershell-within-a-c-application/).